# Trying to get a list of graphical elements to toggle between visible and hidden

Tags: flash, alpha

I asked an earlier question and received help. I'm hoping this will be just as easy.

I'm trying to hide a number of graphics on the stage when I press a certain key on my keyboard. Right now I have it so that when the key is pressed, the alpha setting for each element gets set to 1 (100%). When I press another key on my keyboard, the alpha setting gets set back to 0.

However, It appears that only the top 4-5 elements on my list end up being toggled. The rest on the list stay in their current state of visibility. While doing trial and error I did notice that the order of the elements in the coding effected whether or not the toggling actually took place.

For example:

```
if (e.keyCode == 77){
    graphic_1.alpha = 1;
    graphic_2.alpha = 1;
    graphic_3.alpha = 1;
    graphic_4.alpha = 1;
    graphic_5.alpha = 1;
    graphic_6.alpha = 1;

}
```

When testing it out, the last two instances (graphic_5 and graphic_6) remain at 0% alpha. And if I put, say, graphic_6 at the top of the list, they all would remain at 0% alpha. So I figured the order of the list must be important but I can't find anything that answers that question in a way that I could easily understand (emphasis on "easily").

Again, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a bit more context it is had to say for sure, but it sounds like you're running into an error when trying to set the alpha value on graphic_5 and graphic_6?

So when graphic_6 is at the bottom, the code will run run, setting the alpha value of each element, until it finds an error.

I would guess that the error will be something like "cannot set property of undefined"? So when you move that item to the top, the error occurs straight away, preventing any further items for being affected?

Comment: ^^ I don't get any compiler errors, and "graphic_6" works fine when listed on its own. But when listed with other graphics, it just stops working for some reason.

Comment: It wouldn't be a compiler error, but a runtime error, that would occur at the moment you tried to execute the code. However since you say that graphic_6 works fine on its own it must be something else. Any chance you could share more code?

Comment: Turns out the client decided not to use that part of the swf file so I don't have to worry about it :). Thanks for trying to help, it's appreciated.